# how to get Horizontal menu go up, it overlaps the header image now

Tags: iphone, html, css

another question related to my previous question
My horizontal menu also goes down a few pixels on my iPhone
see:
[image]
wrong on the IPhone
[image]
Right on the comp

Does anyone know how to fix this? :)
link is here: [Alcmaria home page](https://web.archive.org/web/20100315163652/http://www.alcmariavictrix.nl/Algemeen/test2.html)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your previous post, but are you using tables? If not i suggest that you do, then probably even on the iphone browsser it should look ok.

Comment: no, i'm using divs for the design.. I don't want to use tables. You can see the url at: http://www.alcmariavictrix.nl/Algemeen/test2.html

Comment: It works fine on my iPhone... What kind of iPhone do you have?

Comment: 3GS... You can see that the text is a little bit more down than on a normal browser (Firefox, IE7,8)

Comment: I do not have the same issue as you apparently... I'm using 3G myself and both websites look exactly the same to me.

Comment: Strange, it doesn't look good on the 3GS. I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: maybe you can find something on the internet about the difference in safari browser between 3G and 3GS

Comment: couldn't find anything about that, except that the 3GS is faster :)